# SASS not preprocessed correctly

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sass

I have the following file in my `vendor/assets/stylesheets/templates` folder - `test.css.sass`. In the `application.css` I have added the following line in order to load it:

```
*= require templates/test.css.sass
```

The file is loaded and preprocessed correctly except in the following case:

```
$width: 300

.div
  transform: translate3d(#{$width/5-1}px,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-45deg)
```

I am looking for the following output:

```
.div {
  transform: translate3d(59px, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -45deg);
}
```

and using [this nice converter for validation](http://sassmeister.com/) and it seems that the syntax is correct. Unfortunately, what I am getting in my application is this:

```
.div {
  transform: translate3d(60 -1px, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 90deg);
}
```

Could anyone tell why instead calculation, I am getting concatenation?

---

Details:

- Rails 4.0.2
- Sass 3.2.12 (Media Mark)
- ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-linux]
- this code `background-position: -#{($width/5)*2}px 0px` is working
- server restarted several times too

Comment: Did my answer resolve your issue? Let me know.

Comment: @KirtiThorat Thanks a lot. Works as expected. Sorry for the late replay - I was not able to test it till now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
$width: 300  

.div
  transform: translate3d(#{($width/5) - 1px},0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-45deg)
```

**NOTE:**

You can ignore the round bracket surrounding `($width/5)`.